# Display the value of a certain firebase child in a label

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to display the value of a certain firebase child's data in a label.

My code is as follows:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

               for (_, value) in users {
                   if let fullName = value["name"] as? String {
                       if let role = value["role"] as? String {
                           if let mtid = value["mtid"] as? Int {

                               let userNAME = fullName
                               let userROLE = role
                               let userMTID = mtid

                                 print("ID: \(mtid) and NAME: \(fullName) and ROLE: \(role)")

                                  self.mtidLabel.text = userMTID
                                  self.roleLabel.text = userROLE
                                  self.nameLabel.text = userNAME
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
})
```

My Database is as follows:

```
 users:
    - 1234567
        * mtid: 1234567
        * name: "John Smith"
        * role: "coordinator"
    - 2278433
        * mtid: 2278433
        * name: "John Doe"
        * role: "developer"
    - 2317894
        * mtid: 2317894
        * name: "Doe Smith"
        * role: "crew"
```

Essentially, if the user enters a string of numbers in a text box, such as 2317894 I want it to display the child's mtid value as 2317894, the name as "Doe Smith" and the role as "crew" all in separate text boxes.

When I use the above code it only chooses one of the options to display and prints all of the options to the console.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `for (YOURTEXT, value) in users`  and make the comparison

Comment: @WeiJay If I put anything other than _ I get tones of errors. What would I replace the _ with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question.
I changed the following in my code

Removed `for (_, value) in users`

Changed `let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]` to `let users = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary`

Added `.child(self.TEXTBOX_THAT_CONTAINS_CHILD_NUMBER_EG_1234567.text!)` inbetween `ref.child("users")` and `.queryOrderedByKey()`

Final Code:

```
ref.child("users").child(self.TEXTBOX_THAT_CONTAINS_CHILD_NUMBER_EG_1234567.text!).queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  print(snapshot)
  let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
     if let fullName = snapshotValue["name"] as? String {
      if let role = snapshotValue["role"] as? String {
       if let mtid = snapshotValue["mtid"] as? Int {
         let userNAME = fullName
         let userROLE = role
         let userMTID = mtid
         print("ID: \(mtid) and NAME: \(fullName) and ROLE: \(role)")

         self.mtidLabel.text = userMTID
         self.roleLabel.text = userROLE
         self.nameLabel.text = userNAME
       }
      }
     }

})
```